# String Format works fine through Java's SimpleDateFormat and not with JodaTime's DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am working with **Hibernate Validator**.

I have a **java.util.Date** object and it is retrieved through reflection how a String due the following:

```
Object dateDeathObject = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, "dateDeath");
logger.info("dateDeathObject: {}", dateDeathObject);
```

The output always has the following format:

```
- dateDeathObject: Mon Sep 01 16:01:42 PET 2014
```

Using the [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The pattern is `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Therefore with JDK 8 from the String (that represents the **Date.toString()** of some Date value) I can get again the original Date representation object to perform later some validation

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse((String) dateDeathObject);
logger.info("date: {}", date);
```

And works fine

I can see in the output the following:

- dateDeathObject: Mon Sep 01 16:01:42 PET 2014
- date: Mon Sep 01 16:01:42 PET 2014

The problem is with JodaTime, how an alternative to use java.util.Date.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime( (String) dateDeathObject );
logger.info("dt: {}", dt);
```

Observe the same `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` pattern, but I get instead the following error:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon Sep 01 16:01:42 PET 2014" is malformed at "PET 2014"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
    at com.manuel.jordan.validation.support.DateDeathValidator.isValid(DateDeathValidator.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:283)
    ... 38 more
```

I am confused about `is malformed at "PET 2014"`. What is missing with JodaTime?

Comment: if hour = 16, shouldn't you use HH instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right, wondered why SimpleDateFormat did not throw an exception. Even updating the format for JodaTime, the same error message appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PET is not listed in the [list of joda-time supported timezones](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). You might try [updating the database](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/tz_update.html). Hope that helps, leave a comment if you're still having trouble.